# migrate MySQL database with MySQL Workbench CE failed on table with blob data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, blob

I am using MySQL Workbench CE to migrate one schema from a server to another, all table is migrated successfully, except one table with blob data.

The error message is :

```
Found record bigger than max_allowed_packet.
```

I have set the `max_allowed_packet` to 1M on target server, and restarted MySQL, but still got the same error.

And I checked data in that table:

```
select max(OCTET_LENGTH(file_Data)) from attachment;
------
680960
select sum(OCTET_LENGTH(file_Data)) from attachment;
------
5165578
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: @RickJames bigger than sum of all blob columns or max ?

Comment: Try 2M, in case it is using hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to 1G in your session

```
SET max_allowed_packet = 1073741824;
```

You can do so because MySQL will not immediately allocate it. A packet can grow. Please note how [it mentions this in the MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet):

> The packet message buffer is initialized to [**net_buffer_length**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) bytes, but can grow up to [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) bytes when needed. This value by default is small, to catch large (possibly incorrect) packets.
>
> You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or long strings. It should be as big as the largest BLOB you want to use. The protocol limit for [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is 1GB. The value should be a multiple of 1024; nonmultiples are rounded down to the nearest multiple.

You should go ahead and add [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=1G
```

That way it is globally available for all incoming connections when you restart mysql. You don't have to restart mysql right now. You can just run:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1073741824;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: thanks sir, one more little question why max_allowed_packet = 1M is not enough, while the max length of my blob column is 680960 which is lower than 1M, 1M = 1024 * 1024 = 1048576, did I calculate it  right ?